# How can I hide the taxonomy term icon?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, theming

By default, taxonomy terms on a node display with a tag icon:

[image]

What's the easiest way to get rid of that icon? Just use `hide($content['fieldname']);` in my node template and rewrite it the way I want? Or is there a config option somewhere that I've missed that would let me turn it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am almost sure it`s generated by your theme with css. So you can use firebug to find this line and delete background and padding of this element.